# java operator precedence y = x+ (x=10);

Tags: java, operator-precedence

Let's consider

```
int x=1;
int y1 = (x=10) + x;
System.out.println(y1);
// prints 20

x = 1;
int y2 = x + (x=10);
System.out.println(y2);
// prints 11
```

In the first example, () is executed first as it has the highest precedence; sets `x` value to 10 and hence the right-hand operand (x) gets the new value 10 and so `y1 = 10+10 = 20`

In the second example, the left-hand operand 'x' gets its value 1, then () is executed and x gets its new value 10, so `y2 = 1+10 = 11;`

Why in the 2nd example, () doesn't get executed first; so (x=10) gets executed first and the left-hand operand x should be set to its new value 10 and hence y2 = 20; but it didn't happen this way?

Comment: Don't confuse precedence with evaluation order of the operands.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the operands are simply evaluated left-to-right. The parentheses in the right-hand operand don't change the fact that the left-hand operand gets evaluated first.

Comment: Don't believe. Be certain. See [Java Language Specification §15.7 Evaluation Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7): *The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, **from left to right**.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to think about `int z = f() + g()`, i.e. invoking two methods. Why would `g()` be invoked first? What about `int z = f() + (g())` (mind the additional parenthesis)? Left to right is what is happening, where `(x=10)` is just a construct that - when evaluated - assigns to `x` and returns `10` to where this construct is used.